# Extract numbers from a line of string in c++

Tags: c++, string, stream, extract, stringstream

I am making a natural language calculator in C++. The user will input a line of string for calculation. The program will extract the numbers and the operation and apply it accordingly. Following is part of my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inp;
    float n1,n2;
    string s1,s2;

    cout<<"Enter your string"<<endl;
    getline(cin,inp);

    stringstream ss;
    ss.str(inp);

    ss>>s1>>n1>>s2>>n2;
}
```

The program will run successfully if the user enters in correct format i.e Add 2 and 3, Subtract 8 from 12. 
But the problem is in two cases

1. If the user enters in some other format like "7 plus 6".
2. Even in the correct format but only one number "square root of 25".

Is there a solution which can extract the floats regardless of the position or number of floats?

Thanks

Comment: [`find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Comment: @NathanOliver Huh? What're you doing to `find()` exactly? Each digit one by one?

Comment: You should probably read each word one at a time and use a state machine. That way you'll always know when a number is expected to come next.

Comment: @Barry you could `find()` a number and then the first white space after the number

Comment: @NathanOliver I assume you mean [`find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)?

Comment: @Barry Nope.  You can use `find()` and `substr()` in a loop to find all sequences of numbers in a string and extract them.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is literally extract the `float`s, you can take advantage of the fact that [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) can additionally return where it leaves off, which you can use to determine if the entire "word" is a `float` (e.g. for "6c") and catch the `invalid_argument` for words that are definitely not floats (e.g. for "plus"):

```
std::vector<float> getFloats(const std::string& s) {
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string word;
    std::vector<float> result;

    size_t pos = 0;
    while (iss >> word) {
        try {
            float f = std::stof(word, &pos);
            if (pos == word.size()) {
                result.push_back(f);
            }   
        }   
        catch (std::invalid_argument const& ) { 
            // no part of word is a float
            continue;
        }   
    }   

    return result;
}
```

With that, `getFloats("7 plus 6")` yields `{7, 6}` and `getFloats("square root of 25")` yields `{25}`.